# Regex Capture Parts of Line

Tags: regex

I have been struggling to capture a part of an snmp response.

**Text**

```
IF-MIB::ifDescr.1 = 1/1/g1, Office to DMZ
```

**Regex**

```
(?P<ifDescr>(?<=ifDescr.\d = ).*)
```

**Current Capture**

```
1/1/g1, Office to DMZ
```

How to capture only?

`1/1/g1`

`Office to DMZ`

**EDIT**

`1/1/g1`

This should match the digit and forward slashes for the port notation in the snmp response.

```
(?P<ifDescr>(?<=ifDescr.\d = )\d\/\d\/g\d)
```

Link to [regexr](http://regexr.com/5pogl)

`Office to DMZ`

This should start the match past the port notation and capture remaining description.

```
(?P<ifDescr>(?<=ifDescr.\d = \d\/\d\/g\d, ).*)
```

Link to [regexr](http://regexr.com/5poh4)

Comment: Can you just skip the first 2 'columns'?

Comment: The link to the regexr site is nice but you need to add all the relevant examples into your question with an explanation of whether they should work or not, what they should return, etc.

Comment: \d+  for one or more digits

Comment: What's your end goal?  To just have the 1/1/g## ?

Comment: And what language are you targeting this expression for? javascript?

Comment: Did this answer not work out? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66882728/5424988

Comment: Is see that you have posted another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66898114/regex-matching-number-of-digits Did [my posted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66882728/5424988) not work out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is what you are looking for

```
= (.+), (.+)
```

It looks for "= " then captures all until a comma and then everything afterwards. It returns

```
1/1/g1
Office to DMZ
```

as requested.

See it working on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yEhCj5/1).

Comment: Thank you.  Nice and simple clean solution.  Something I need to work on! :-)

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, could you please try following regex with PCRE options available.

```
(?<=IF-MIB::ifDescr)\.\d+\s=\s\K(?:\d+\/){2}g(?:\d+)
```

[Here is Online demo of above regex](https://regex101.com/r/edKZ1L/1/)

OR with a little variation use following:

```
(?<=IF-MIB::ifDescr)\.\d+\s=\s\K(?:(?:\d+\/){2}g\d+)
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
(?<=IF-MIB::ifDescr)  ##using look behind to make sure all mentioned further conditions must be preceded by this expression(IF-MIB::ifDescr)
\.\d+\s=\s            ##Matching literal dot with digits one or more occurrences then with 1 or more occurrences of space = followed by one or more occurrences of spaces.
\K                    ##\K is GNU specific to simply forget(kind of) as of now matched regex and consider values in regex for further given expressions only.
(?:\d+\/){2}g(?:\d+)  ##Creating a non-capturing group where matching 1 or more digits with g and 1 or more digits.
```

***Without PCRE flavor:*** To get values in 1st capture group try following, confirmed by OP in comments about its working.

```
(?<=IF-MIB::ifDescr)\.\d+\s=\s((\d+\/){2}g\d+)
```

Comment: Nice usage of `\K`.

Comment: This works in the online demo and looks promising but I get in error when I include it in the script.  **bad escape \K at position ##**

Comment: @pablo808, yeah `\K` is a GNU specific feature I believe, could you please try `(?<=IF-MIB::ifDescr)(?:\.\d+\s=\s)(?:\d+\/){2}g(?:\d+)` once and let me know if this helps you? Once you update this is working, I will update my answer as per that then, cheers.

Comment: No joy.. This matched **.10 = 1/1/g1**

Comment: @pablo808, ok one more try here: How about `(?<=IF-MIB::ifDescr)\.\d+\s=\s((\d+\/){2}g\d+)` using this one once(creating only 1 capturing group here)? Kindly do let me know if this helps you.

Comment: this amended regex worked with capture group 1. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could just use [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66881173/2386774) I gave you yesterday and split the first return group, `1/1/g10`, by '/' and get the third part.

```
1/1/g10
```

split by '/' gives

```
1
1
g10 <- third part
```

Why use a more complicated regex when you can use simple code to accomplish the task?

Comment: @CinCout I don't really think this is a dupe but I do think it's kinda close. I think he's just asking questions piecemeal instead of asking one good, complete question that gets everything he wants. If you look at his profile, there's even another related question to this and the one I linked here.

Answer (score 2):

Here are my attempts.

```
const string pattern = ".* = (.*), (.*)";
var r = Regex.Match(s, pattern);

const string pattern2 = ".* = ([0-9a-zA-Z\\/]*), (.*)";
var r2 = Regex.Match(s, pattern2);
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I managed to get the port by: (?P<ifDescr>(?<=ifDescr.\d = )\d\/\d\/g\d)

Answer (score 1):

Using the named capture group `ifDescr` to capture the value `1/1/g1` you can use a match instead of lookarounds.

*(Note to escape the dot \. to match it literally)*

```
ifDescr\.\d+ = (?P<ifDescr>\d+\/\d+\/g\d+),
```

The pattern matches:

- `ifDescr\.\d+ =`  Match `ifDescr.` and 1+ digits followed by  `=`
- `(?P<ifDescr>` Named group *ifDescr*

  - `\d+\/\d+\/g\d+` Match 1+ digits `/` 1+ digits `/g` and 1+ digits
- `),` Close group and match the trailing comma

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z3b3sz/1)

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

`ifDescr\.\d+\s=\s((?:\d\/){2}g\d+)`

The resultant capture groups contain the intended result. Note that `\d+` accepts one or more digits, so you don't need the OR operator as used by you.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D0wpGd/16)

Alternatively, it looks like that the number after `g` will always be the number after `ifDescr.`. If that is the case, do this:

`ifDescr\.(\d+)\s=\s((?:\d\/){2}g\1)`

This basically captures the number in a group, then reuses it to match using backreference (note the usage of `\1`). The intended result in this case is available in the second capturing group.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/D0wpGd/17)

Comment: Hi, I only need to match the port notation.  ie. 1/1/g10 or 1/1/g6

Comment: It's matching **ifDescr.10 = 1/1/g10**.