# Regex matching number of digits

Tags: regex

Based off this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66897220/regex-match-1-or-2-digits-without-error-look-behind-requires-fixed-width-patter), I'm trying to match all the ports including g10.

```
IF-MIB::ifDescr.10 = 1/1/g10, Office to DMZ
IF-MIB::ifDescr.6 = 1/1/g6, Office to DMZ
IF-MIB::ifDescr.4 = 1/1/g4, Office to DMZ
```

This is a partial match:

```
(?:(?<=ifDescr\.\d = )|(?<=ifDescr\.\d\d = ))(?P<ifDescr>((\d\/\d\/g\d))|(\d\/\d\/g\d\d))
```

I can't get the 2nd half to match both g6 and g10.

Example [here](https://regexr.com/5pr8d).

**SOLUTION**

Thank you to all those who answered.  Here are the two answers I used that used Capture 1 Group.

```
ifDescr\.\d+\s=\s((?:\d\/){2}g\d+)
```

```
(?<=IF-MIB::ifDescr)\.\d+\s=\s((\d+\/){2}g\d+)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex Capture Parts of Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66881097/regex-capture-parts-of-line)